# Error in syntax while writing a procedure to hash password in Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting a syntax error while trying to create this procedure to hash a password. Not sure why it says there are syntax errors.

The error I keep getting is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@pFirstName varchar(255),
>       @pLastName varchar(255),
>       @pEmail varchar(255),
>       @' at line 2

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Users`
@pFirstName varchar(255),
@pLastName varchar(255),
@pEmail varchar(255),
@pPassword NVARCHAR(50),
@pType int(11),
@pCreatedAt datetime,
@pUpdatedAt datetime,
@pUser_type enum('admin','project-manager','lawyer','anonymous-client','client','external-client','intake-bot'),
@pUndashPassword NVARCHAR(50),
@responseMessage NVARCHAR(250) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN TRY

    insert into `Users` (`firstName`,`lastName`,`email`, `password`,`type`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`user_type`, `PasswordHash`)
    VALUES(@pFirstName, @pLastName, @pEmail, @pPassword, @pType, @pCreatedAt, @pUpdatedAt, @pUser_type, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pUndashPassword))

    SET @responseMessage='Success'

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @responseMessage=ERROR_MESSAGE() 
END CATCH

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare variables used in a SP in MySQL you will need to do it in this way:

```
STORE PROCEDURE someThing(in Var1 INT, in Var2 VARCHAR(20)....)
```

I mean you need:

- Identify if the element is an `input` value, an `outpu` value or maybe both `inputouput`
- Name of the variable
- Type of data will be stored in this variable

Now those are the parameters of your SP but if you need variables inside of your SP, the right sintax is:

```
DECLARE anotherValue INT DEFAULT 10;
```

I mean you will need:

- `DECLARE` statment
- Name of the variable
- Type of data will be stored
- Optionally you can set a `DEFAULT` value

**Check this example**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE EXAMPLE1(IN idUser INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE Total INT;
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO Total 
    FROM users 
    WHERE users.id = idUser;
    SELECT Total;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

After you call it in this way:

```
CALL EXAMPLE1(1);
```

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're accustomed to Microsoft SQL Server syntax.

MySQL is not the same implementation of SQL as Microsoft SQL Server. MySQL has its own syntax, which is different. I notice quite a few things in your example that won't work in MySQL. I haven't tested your procedure to see if this is a complete list, so treat this as just a sample of the mistakes.

- MySQL does not use the `@` sigil for procedure parameters or local variables. See my answer to [Mysql stored procedure gives unknown column error when executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070946/mysql-stored-procedure-gives-unknown-column-error-when-executed/58071023#58071023)
- `TRY`/`CATCH` is a Microsoft syntax. MySQL does not use that, it uses a syntax for declaring "handlers" for error states: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html
- `SET NOCOUNT ON` is also Microsoft syntax. MySQL does not have any equivalent feature.
- `SHA_512()` is not a function in MySQL. You should use `SHA2(<string>, 512)`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2

You should read some MySQL documentation about stored procedure syntax.

The manual is for reference. All the syntax is documented, but it's not a task-oriented document, so it's difficult to learn MySQL stored procedures from the manual alone.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-compound-statements.html

There's also an O'Reilly book, which is getting a bit old now, but undoubtedly still helpful, because MySQL stored procedure features haven't changed much: [MySQL Stored Procedure Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100896.do)
.